invalid_request trying to login with google in React Native expo
I am making an app with React Native and Expo. my code is:
const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    androidClientId: "x.-x.apps.googleusercontent.com"
});

in the console of google, I have the android client of OAuth 2.0 with correct package name and SHA-1 configurated.
Also de OAuth Consent Screen is created.
But when I try login with google, this error is in the screen: (IMG)
and the error details are:

Error 400: invalid_request
Detalles de la solicitud: redirect_uri=exp://x.x.x.x:8081 flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

I don't know what more to do, there is not much data about this error on internet, I tried create a new app and a new Oauth client but it did not work

check redirect URI from google API console and try with updating expo configurations
